# 403 forbidden : You don't have permission to access this resource. Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server Port 443

Tags: .net, angular, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have installed the certificate but when I try to access the url with https it gives me 403 forbidden error, but when I try to use it with http it is working fine.

```
Apache Version 2.4.18

Document root /home/ubuntu/app
```

I have installed the certificate in /etc/ssl/certs/ and I have following files:

1. test.key
2. test.ca-bundle
3. test.crt

In apache i have placed .conf file in
1. /etc2/apach2/sites-available/test.com.conf
2. /etc2/apach2/sites-enable/test.com.conf

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/aspnetcoredemo-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/aspnetcoredemo-access.log common
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://test.com/"
    
    <Directory /home/ubuntu/app>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin admin@test.com
  ServerName test.com
  ServerAlias www.test.com
  DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/app

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  SSLEngine on

  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/test_com.crt
  SSLCACertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/test_com.ca-bundle
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/certs/test_com.key
  
  <Directory /home/ubuntu/app>
             Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
             AllowOverride All
             Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also check and the ssl certificate was installed correctly:

[image]

The website is create using .net core.

I don't know what wrong I am doint here.

Comment: For plain HTTP you have an explicit `allow from all` while you don't have this for HTTPS.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich With Apache 2.2

`Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all`

With Apache 2.4

`Require all granted`